# has_one but belongs_to only one of many choices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a map location object. A player, which has_one location. Enemies/NPC's which have_one location. How to handle the belongs_to, or do I not need it?
So its always a one to one, its just a one to one with different objects.

```
class Player
  has_one :location
end

class Npc
  has_one :location
end

class Location
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :npc
end
```

That doesn't seem right but it represents sort of what I want, so that if I only had a location, I could get back to what is on that location. Might be special items there in the future like, a mine.  All very different models but when you look at a place on a map, you want to know what is there.

```
class Mine
   has_one :location
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't a player and npc `belong_to` a location? Then you could use `location.player` or `location.npc`, etc.

Comment: So does location, get neither belong_to or has_one? and yes, I want to do location.player, or location.npc, depending on which object is at that location, and I have a list of locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player
  belongs_to :location
end

class Npc
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location
  has_many :player
  has_many :npc
end
```

I think what u want to do is this.

So then u use it on view u can use Player.location and Npc.location
It means location_id is saved to player and npc table.

Comment: I'm starting from the location, so I have a list of locations and want to know what is on them.  A specific location, x,y, will only have player, or NPC, so has many doesn't seem right.